# Duplicating characters using sed

Tags: sed, computer-science

I am working on trying to duplicate characters on certain words, but the sed script I wrote is not quite doing what I want it to. For example, I am trying to duplicate each character in a words like so:

> FILE into FFIILLEE

I know how to remove the duplicate letters with :

> sed s/\(.\)\1/\1/g' file.txt

This is the sed script I wrote, but it just ends up duplicating the whole word and I just get:

FILE FILE

This is what I wrote:

> sed 's/[A-Z]*/& &/g' file.txt

How can I grab each letter and duplicate just the letter?

Comment: Stack Overflow would probably be a better place for this question.

Comment: Agreed with above, but basically I think what you're doing wrong is putting the && outside of the *. I.e. you're matching everything then repeating, whereas you should be doing match, repeat, match, repeat.

Comment: This looks like it is not quite appropriate for MSE. Meanwhile I suggest you consider using Perl e.g. the command "perl -pe 's/(\w)/\1\1/g;'" Perl can certainly  do everything sed can and much more.

Answer (score 1):

A slight variation on your first script should work:

```
sed 's/\(.\)/\1\1/g' file.txt
```

Translation: For every character seen, replace it by itself followed by itself.

Comment: An alternative that's a bit easier to read: `sed 's/./&&/g' - not so many confusing escapes...

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/[[:alpha:]]/&&/g' file.txt
```

- `[:alpha:]`class is the whole scope of letter available, you could extend with `[:alnum:]`including digit
- `&` in replacement pattern is the whole search pattern matching. In this case 1 letter
- `g` for each possible occurence

Your probleme was to use the `*` in search pattern that mean all occurence of previous pattern so the pattern is the whole word at once and not every letter of this word